# Deflating GDP using OECD data

Tags: macroeconomics

I would like to know how to find a Euro zone country real quarterly gdp growth, using the OECD database.

We have [Quarterly GDP](https://data.oecd.org/gdp/quarterly-gdp.htm#indicator-chart), and [CPI](https://data.oecd.org/price/inflation-cpi.htm#indicator-chart). 
How should I proceed?

If it's not possible, which database can I use to obtain it?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: That Quarterly GDP chart looks as if it is already the percentage change in real GDP (for example put "Time" on "Annual" and note that the effects of the 1973 and 1979 oil price shocks are negative rather than positive)

Comment: @Henry Nice! Thanks. I never thought of that 'trick' to see if a dataset is in real or nominal terms...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That Quarterly GDP chart looks as if it is already the percentage change in real GDP (for example put "Time" on "Annual" and note that the effects of the 1973 and 1979 oil price shocks are negative rather than positive)

[image: https://data.oecd.org/gdp/quarterly-gdp.htm#indicator-chart]